# How to maintain decimal values with subtractions in java

Tags: java, double, decimal

If I do:

```
double unavailabilityInitialElement = Math.pow((1.0-availabilityInitialElementInstance), instancesUsedInitialElement);

double availabilityInitialElement = 1.0 - unavailabilityInitialElement;
```

I receive that `unavailabilityInitialElement` is `1.0025443684293908E-20` and `availabilityInitialElement` is equal to `1`.

I would like to have a decimal value like `unavailabilityInitialElement` so that it is shown: `0.99999999999999999999899746` because I cannot approximate it. I can approximate it if and only if `unavailabilityInitialElement`  is less than `E-24`, but in this case i would like to approximate it at the minimum possible value (so `0.99999999999999999999` for example).

Could you please help me writing the right code?
Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but I guess `BigDecimal` might be worth a look.

Comment: Within the precision of double 1-1e-24 is closer to 1.0 than to the next smaller representable number (approx 0.999999999999999). So the answer 1 is actually more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## BigDecimal

If double precision isn't good enough, you will have to use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) objects for your calculations.

```
double d = 1.0025443684293908E-20;
BigDecimal num = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(num);

System.out.println(result.toPlainString());
// 0.999999999999999999989974556315706092
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do. It works perfectly. Thank you so much @folkol